# Format "n" and "k" with brackets in python but its not doing what I would like

Tags: python, arrays, printing, formatting

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
d = len(sys.argv)>3
n = int(sys.argv[1])
k = int(sys.argv[2])
A = []
for i in range(n):
    A.append(i)
if d: 
    print("[{0} {1}]".format(n,k))
val = combinations(A, k)
for i in val:
    print(i)
```

I am using this code to print

`[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 2]`

But it keeps printing with parenthesis (like below) instead and am not sure why it's not working(the spacing isn't messed up)

`(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 2)`

Comment: So what are the values for `n` and `k`?

Comment: We'll need to see more code than this. Where are `n` and `k` defined? The print statement looks like it works fine [in this demo.](https://repl.it/repls/AlarmedBuoyantDebuggers)

Comment: I recommend leaving the question with all of the source code present - it seems the error is with your initial statements, not with your print statement. It's also important to know where `d` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it's printing "parenthesis", it's working fine!

```
for i in [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2]]:
    print("[{0}, {1}]".format(*i))
    # [0, 1]
    # [0, 2]
    # [1, 2]
```

---

Update:
I think what you trying to do is parsing the tuple to list when printing it.

```
# Keep in mind there is no loops here so you printing this only once 
if d:
    print("[{0} {1}]".format(n,k))

# This is where you got the tuples from
# val = combinations(A, k)

# You can parse that to list before printing 
val = [list(v) for v in  combinations(A, k)]
for i in val:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is likely never being called. Assuming you invoke your program as `foo.py num1 num2`, `sys.argv` will have 3 elements: `['foo.py', 'num1', 'num2]`. This means `d = len(sys.argv)>3` will always be false.

Maybe try `d = len(sys.argv)=3` instead?